# check every cell in a range for a specific string?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a VBA code by which I can check every cell in a range with a specific text?

```
EG: for each cell in range (a:a)
    if value of cell = "specific text"
    do this
    else 
    do that
```

*

How to do this in VBA Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go, but please try to find on google first

```
Sub eachCell()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:D21")
        If (c.Value = "mytext") Then    'if value of cell = "specific text"
            c.Value = "other text" 'do this
            Else
            c.Value = "other text 2"  'do that
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the meaning of   `c.value ="other text` ?

Comment: it corresponds to "do this" in your code. it will change the value of the cell to "other text"

Answer (score 0):

Using a Find loop will be quicker than looking at each cell

```
Sub Sample_Find()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim FoundAt As String


    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns(1)

    SearchString = "specific text"

    Set rng2 = rng1.Find(SearchString, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = rng2
        FoundAt = rng2.Address
        MsgBox "do something here " & FoundAt
        Do
            Set rng2 = rng1.FindNext(After:=rng2)

            If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                If rng2.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & rng2.Address
                MsgBox "do something here " & rng2.Address
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: why not go for the `AutoFilter` , that would be even faster, no ?

Comment: what is autofilter ?
how do I use it here?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to answer your post, using the `AutoFilter`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_AutoFilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SearchString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim VisRng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Set Rng = ws.Columns(1)

SearchString = "specific text"

Rng.AutoFilter
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchString

' set another range to only visible cells after the Filter was applied
Set VisRng = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Not VisRng Is Nothing Then

    ' Option 1: show every cell that a SearchString was found
    For Each c In VisRng
        MsgBox "String match of " & SearchString & " found as cell " & c.Address
    Next c

    ' Option 2: show all the cells that SearchString was found (in 1 message)
    MsgBox "String match of " & SearchString & " found as cells " & VisRng.Address
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: needs error handling for specialcells (in case of no matches).

Comment: I am getting an error : `autofilter method of range class failed`